# How to suppress the captions of subfigures in LoF using \subfigure

Tags: captions, subfloats

I am writing a thesis and I have to use the `\subfigure` environ and not `\caption`. 
The problem is I do not want that the captions of the individual subfigures appear on list of figures (LoF) and only the caption of the main figure should appear?

In the following mwe, still `(a)` and `(b)` are showing in the LoF. Any help please.

```
documentclass{article}
        \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
        \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
        \RequirePackage{subfigure}
        \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering     %%% not \center
        \subfigure[]{\label{fig:a}\includegraphics[width=70mm]{f9.eps}}
        \subfigure[]{\label{fig:b}\includegraphics[width=70mm]{f10.eps}}
    \caption{(a) this is fig 1 (b) this is fig 2. }
    \label{L50}
    \end{figure}
```

Comment: Hi. Please tell your school that "this package should not be used in combination with hyperref and links. This is well-documented" (TeXnician [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380193/caption-in-subfigures-double-column-text)) and that it should be avoided and replaced by `caption` or `subcaption` if possible in any way. `subfigure`'s capabilities have been superseded by these alternatives.

Comment: \subfigure[\empty] and \subfigure (no {}) worked for me. It still increments the subfigure counter, so the `\label`s work.

Comment: @JohnKormylo thank you. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `subfig` package.

Hope the below MWE helps you:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering     %%% not \center
    \subfloat[Sub-Caption a]{\fbox{\label{fig:a}\includegraphics[width=70mm]{figure1.eps}}}\ 
    \subfloat[Sub-Caption b]{\fbox{\label{fig:b}\includegraphics[width=70mm]{figure2.eps}}}\\
\caption{Caption here}\label{fig1}
\end{figure}

Figure \ref{fig1}

Sub Figure \ref{fig:a}--\ref{fig:b}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: The problem is I am not allowed to use my own package in the standard template defined by University office. I've to use the \subfigure. Anyways thanks for the suggestion.