# Caption in subfigures, double column text

Tags: captions

I would like to be able to make a small caption for each of the figures here, plus the caption for the overall. Could you please help me?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[h]
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.47\linewidth]{example-image}\hfil
    \includegraphics[width=0.47\linewidth]{example-image-a}\par\medskip
    \includegraphics[width=0.47\linewidth]{example-image-b}\hfil
    \includegraphics[width=0.47\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\caption{caption here}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have a look at the `subcaption` package.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. However, can I still use it in [twocolumn]{article}?

Comment: There are many different subfigure packages out there, and all of them are glorified minipages.  Check out the Related questions to the right for examples.  I would recommend the subcaption package (and stay away from KOMA).  Also, figure* only recognizes t, b, or p (not h).

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved by using `subfig` package.

MWE in below:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

Figure \ref{fig1} % Cross reference for the Main 

Sub Figure \ref{fig1a}--\ref{fig1f} % cross reference for the sub figures

\begin{figure*}[h]
\centering
    \subfloat[Sub-Caption a]{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.47\linewidth]{figure1}}\label{fig1a}}\ 
    \subfloat[Sub-Caption b]{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.47\linewidth]{figure2}}\label{fig1b}}\\
    \subfloat[Sub-Caption c]{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.47\linewidth]{figure1}}\label{fig1c}}\
    \subfloat[Sub-Caption d]{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.47\linewidth]{figure2}}\label{fig1d}}\\
    \subfloat[Sub-Caption e]{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.47\linewidth]{figure1}}\label{fig1e}}\
    \subfloat[Sub-Caption f]{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.47\linewidth]{figure2}}\label{fig1f}}
\caption{caption here}\label{fig1}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: subfig]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. However, can I still use it in [twocolumn]{article}?

Comment: yes, that was a typo...

Comment: I have corrected it in my answer.

Comment: @Auryn2 Please note that this package should not be used in combination with `hyperref` and links. This is well-documented. Package `subcaption` is more recent.

Comment: Is there any other package I can use instead of hyperref with the same functionality?

Comment: There are other packages which add to hyperref, but they either require or automatically load hyperref.  Search "Cross Reference" on this site for examples.

Comment: Hi, yes, but in the pdf the reference to the image doesn't give me the option to "jump" to the image/equation directly, as by using hyperref.